# Django: One-to-many relation for [0, 1] cardinality

Tags: python, django, django-models, data-modeling

Imagine having two models:

```
class Service(models.Model):
  key_service_name = models.ForeignKey(Key_service_type, related_name='Service_key_service_names', null=False)
  service_hourly_wage_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True)
  service_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True)

class ServiceAdditionalInfo(models.Model):
  service = models.ForeignKey(Service, related_name='Service_additional_info_services', null=False)
  fixed_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True)
```

Amongst other info, the Service class serializer features this field description:

```
service_additional_info = ServiceAdditionalInfoSerializer(read_only = True, many=False, source = 'Service_additional_info_services')
```

In practice, one Service instance may be referenced by 0 or 1 ServiceAdditionalInfo instance.
The serializer understandably returns a list while I would definitely prefer a dictionary.

My question: Is this the recommended way of modelling the relation?
If so, is there a django-built-in mechanism to return a dict for such cases?

For the latter case I know how to work around the issue, but since I would like to use the framework in the intended way, I'm very curious if there's something I missed regarding modelling and serializers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your foreign key with a [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

> A one-to-one relationship. Conceptually, this is similar to a
>   ForeignKey with unique=True, but the “reverse” side of the relation
>   will directly return a single object.

This is the preferable way of mapping a relationship when there can be exactly one or zero objects related to each other.

As for generating a single dictionary that contains data from both models, you will need to subclass the model serializer.

Comment: Tried it, works perfectly. Makes the code base a lot more elegant (as when using a foreign key and a work-around when converting a list to a dictionary).
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to have been of help.